# C pointer to array of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

How to solve matrix problem where values are set of string. I want to use pointer.  Following is the warning:

"warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"

```
char *country[]={"USA\n","UK\n","Chaina\n","Singapore\n","Scotland\n"};
for (int i =0; i <5; i++) {
     printf("\n CHECK val=%s\n",country[i]);    
}
char *(*cp)[5]=&country[2];
for (int i =0; i <3; i++) {
    printf("\n POINTER  val=%s\n",(*cp)[i]);
}
```

Comment: England-and-Wales*  (this comment future-proofed by 2 years)

Answer (score 4):

You get the warning because `&country[2]` does not return a pointer to an array of five C strings. However, you do not need such a pointer, because a simple `char **` pointer will let you create an alias to the middle of an array:

```
char **cp = &country[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
    printf("\n POINTER  val=%s\n", cp[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/TXn0wG)

**Note:** You do not need to have `\n` characters in both the string literals and the `printf` format string, unless you want double-spacing.

Comment: @Flair You are welcome! If this answers your question, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors that the problem is solved, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.